# how to display the json div class with the loop each ()

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm trying to display the return json one section, but display all in the same div

```
<section>
<div class="conteudo">
    <div class="foto"> FOTO </div>
    <div class="inf"> TITULO </div>
    <div class="inf"> DESCRICAO </div>
    <div class="inf"> PRECO </div>
</div>
    <div class="conteudo">
    <div class="foto"> FOTO </div>
    <div class="inf"> TITULO </div>
    <div class="inf"> DESCRICAO </div>
    <div class="inf"> PRECO </div>
```

I try:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "categoria/"+id,
    contentType: "charset=utf-8",
    }).done(function(output){

        json = $.parseJSON(output);

        $('.conteudo').empty();

        $.each(json, function(i, items){

            $('.conteudo').append(


            items.fields['imagem'],
            items.fields['nome_produto'],
            items.fields['descricao'],
            items.fields['preco_produto']
            );


        });


});
```

tried using (.html .appedTo addClass .append) but nothing to get

Comment: please specify how your result should look like?

Comment: `$('.conteudo')` targets multiple divs. You need to target only one at a time . `append()` appends *HTML* elements, where you have just raw data values (that it tries to use as HTML). You need to set the `text` of elements instead,

Comment: TrueBlueAussie: can you give me a simple example for me to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an existing `.conteudo` div as a template, clone that div and replace the text in each field within that div with the data:

```
// take a copy of an existing one as a template
$.each(json, function (i, items) {
    var clone = $('.conteudo:first').clone();
    clone.find('.foto').text(items.fields['imagem']);
    clone.find('.inf:eq(0)').text(items.fields['nome_produto']);
    clone.find('.inf:eq(1)').text(items.fields['descricao']);
    clone.find('.inf:eq(2)').text(items.fields['preco_produto']);
    $('section').append(clone);
});
```

I made you a mockup with a sample JSON object created literally: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/q44mym2d/1/

**Updated to use a simple template**

As you have a requirement to clear out all current items in the section, I would recommend using a template system. My favourite is to simply use a dummy script block to contain the empty template HTML:

e.g

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
    <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="foto"></div>
        <div class="inf"></div>
        <div class="inf"></div>
        <div class="inf"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

`type="text/template"` is an unknown type so all browsers ignore it.

The code then uses the HTML from that element with `html()`.

e.g. I just changed this one line

```
var clone = $($('#template').html());
```

**Updated JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/q44mym2d/2/

This means you can destroy all existing items without concern as the template is separate (and nicely editable).

Comment: Thanks man! :)

Just a question, I'm trying to clear the div with empty () to not be doubled all the time but is not working.
thank you

Comment: Empty will wipe out the child divs. Why do you need to clear it? If you can explain *why* you need to I can suggest *how* to do it :)

Comment: As I click on a menu link, is made an ajax request that returns the json with the products. This json being displayed in these divs.
When you click another category need to clean these products to display the new json with the products.
Thanks man